# HTML: How do I make one form appear on top of another form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form and a table.  I made the "position" of the form "fixed" so that when I scroll down the form is always visible.  However, the table goes over the form and I can't see the form even though it is there on the top of the page.  How do I get this form to stay on top of the page and appear above any other objects in its position?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: adding onto @j08691, JSFiddle it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some reading material:

To get a sense of the default stacking order related to the order of your html elements in the document:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

To influence / override the stacking order with 'z-index':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

To summarize the effects of creating new 'stacking contexts':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I got it to work using z-index.  Thanks

Comment: No problem @amun25. z-index is a strange animal.

Answer (score 0):

Even add the position of the form as either ( 'absolute' or 'relative') in CSS.